# Building own Installer for Game

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, installation

I have made a game and wish to distribute it online. I have spent years playing around with many Installers (InstallWise, InstallShield, etc, etc, etc).

They are very complex, require time and in most cases, a decent amount of money. So I want to write my own Installer, that will install my game for the user.

My game is comprised of:

- DLL files (these will go inside the Game's folder, inside Program Files.
- The application file itself (a single .exe file).

I will also need to create a shortcut on the Desktop (if the user allows) which will launch the .exe in Program Files folder. I can already do this.

I know how to copy and write files to folders. What I am asking is, how do I "pack" the files into my installer file, so that I can give a user a single file to download, which will then "unpack" the game's files into the appropriate location?

I have asked this question 2 years ago on SO and was met with hostility; the person claimed that this is not possible - but incase they haven't noticed, 90% of installers are just a single file, which unpacks its contents into a directory/several directories. So I know it *is* possible.

---

The only way I can think of that I can get this to work is by going over each file that needs to be *packed*, and reading the bytes into the app and storing it into an embedded file. And when the app is run, it will look for embedded files/bytes and write those bytes to new files in the specified locations. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of Wix? http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either save the bytes in your installer, which means that you will need a builder for the actual installer which will use CodeDom.

Or you can download the files from a server, which seems faster in this case.

You choose.

Comment: @George thank you, when you say "builder", what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: The second option you mentioned, isn't this how the Visual Studio 2013 installer works?

Comment: To a builder I refer to an application which by given files will create an installer - by embedding the files inside.

Comment: And yes, the second option is how Visual Studio installer works.

Answer (score 0):

To do so i would use a Self-Extract Zip. this is an exe that will unpack itself with all necessary files then you set the after extract command to call and exe of yours which copy everything where you want and then create yourself link on desktop and such. not very difficult.

In the Self-Extract file you can also specify that the content is extracted in the temp folder of the computer allowing you to find stuff using environment special directory